# Get Foreign key details using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all programs with their university details.. and get it using this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47033187/revisions .. but now if there has same university id it get university details only first one like [this https://ibb.co/2dh1d44](http://this%20https://ibb.co/2dh1d44).. how can I get each every program details with their university details? 
I have theses relationships

**Program model**

```
 public function univesity(){
        return $this->belongsTo(tblUniversity::class,"id");
    }
```

**University model**

```
 public function programs(){
        return $this->hasMany(tblProgram::class);
    }
```

**controller**

```
 public function programGet(){
        $uni = tblProgram::with('univesity')->get();

        return response()->json($uni);
}
```

**university table migration**

```
 Schema::create('tbl_universities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

**program table migration**

```
 Schema::create('tbl_programs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tbl_university_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('program');
            $table->integer('periodMonths');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('tbl_university_id')->references('id')->on('tbl_universities')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

thank you...

Comment: Show your migration or table as well.

Comment: @Laravel Done :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Program model** you need to change as `foreign key` or `primary key`

```
public function univesity(){
    return $this->belongsTo(tblUniversity::class,"tbl_university_id","id");
}
```

same as in **University model**

```
public function programs(){
    return $this->hasMany(tblProgram::class,"tbl_university_id","id");
}
```

Your table name is different. so make sure to add in model

**Program model**

```
protected $table = 'tbl_programs';
```

**University model**

```
protected $table = 'tbl_universities';
```